# I want to use google analytics in my hybird application which is using Onsen ui and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, onsen-ui

I want to use google analytics in my hybird application by using follows code in the index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script>
    // PhoneGap event handler
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("PhoneGap is ready");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
   !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
   (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
   r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
   }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<h1>HelloWorld!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But in the google analytics real-time overview page, I cannot see anything at there.
Anybody knows how to archive it?

Comment: where did you put that code?

Comment: In the index.html above <head> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this that should work (it works for me)

Put this before the `</body>` tag (notice that the tag is the closing one, so the `<script>` is inside the body.

```
<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
<script>
   !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
   (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
   r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
   }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: ok, so you will need to post more code and if possible a working jsFiddle or plunkr... Did you check if the problem is only for live (real time) overview?

Comment: I post my code above, please help me to solve this problem

Comment: you didn't include angular files... try include them, you should have your `<script>` **last** in the `<body>` in this order: google analytics, angular, your angular code. (so the h1 is before the scripts. put all scripts there also loader an phonegap)

Comment: sorry could you share me a simple code which can work?Actually,I just try to use it in a html page which just show "hello world",but it also did not works

Comment: you have phonegap, onsen and so much things together, try remove them and go incremental step by step. You will learn if there is something wrong, I think you are testing it on an actual device after phonegap compilation, ecc ecc. It's very complicated to start immediatly with everything on the line. Try to start from zero adding piece by piece, starting with google default code

Comment: Ok,I will try to do it.Where I can find the google default code?